# Changing Celery Default Queue, Not working properly as expected

Tags: python, celery

I had overridden celery default queue. Below are the settings mentioned.

## Settings

```
BROKER_URL = "amqp://managedbrokerurl/username/"
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'project.env.default'
CELERY_ROUTES = {"app1.tasks.push_api_task": {"queue": "project.env.priority_queue"}}
```

## Workers

```
python manage.py celery worker -n env_worker -Q project.env.default
python manage.py celery worker -n env_worker -Q project.env.priority_queue
```

As per the configuration I am expecting all the tasks except `app1.tasks.push_api_task` should go to queue `project.env.default`.
But a weird issues are happening, for example tasks are going to the `project.env.default` queue as well as the `celery` queue (which is the default if not overridden).

I checked our code base and nowhere have we used the `celery` queue for task publishing.

Please help if you guys had gone through the same problem.

[image: Celery Queue Screen]

Comment: one thing - you should probably use different values for `-n` between workers.

Answer (score 34):

I know this is a really late response, but if people are still running into this problem, the issue is with some of Celery's older documentation. The variable `CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE` is incorrectly given in some of the documentation and should be `CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_QUEUE`

Comment: this took me hours then eventually found this and problem sorted - definitely worth an upvote thank you Dantheman91

Comment: You saved me some extra hours, thank you !

Answer (score -1):

> A worker instance can consume from any number of queues. By default it
>   will consume from all queues defined in the CELERY_QUEUES setting
>   (which if not specified defaults to the queue named celery)

I think you should see [a section of celery docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#queues)

> You can also start multiple workers on the same machine. If you do so
>   **be sure to give a unique name to each individual worker** by specifying
>   a host name with the --hostname|-n argument:

[Source](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#starting-the-worker)

Comment: I had changed the settings as suggested but didn't help me out. below are the settings mentioned                         ######################## Celery Settings #######################
BROKER_URL = ''
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'env.stg.default'
CELERY_QUEUES = (
Queue(
'gm.stg.default',
Exchange('env.stg.default'),
routing_key='env.stg.default'),)
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE = 'direct'